# Troubles in implementing nullptr on VS2013

Tags: c++, c++11, nullptr

I try an official implementation of nullptr

I know with nullptr and std::nullptr_t supported by Compilers, this implementation is meaningless.I am just trying to study C++.

and everything works well by GCC4.9.1 on my PC, both -std=c++03 and -std=c++11, even successful Online @ideone.com GCC4.3.2.

but in VS2013 line 125 goes error2440, conversion failed

```
error C2440: "initialize": cannot convert "const <unnamed-type-my_nullptr>" to "int (__thiscall Test::* )(void) const" in line125
```

>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

// The Official proposal
// http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2431.pdf
const // this is a const object... 
class {
public:
    template<class T> // convertible to any type 
    operator T*() const // of null non-member 
    {
        return 0;
    } // pointer... 

    template<class C, class T> // or any type of null 
    operator T C::*() const // member pointer... 
    {
        return 0;
    }

private:
    void operator&() const; // whose address can't be taken 
} my_nullptr = {}; // and whose name is nullptr


struct Test123 {
    int ABCD, ABC, AB;
    int A;
    int BA, CBA, DCBA;
    struct XYZ {
        char X, Y, Z, W;
    };
    struct {
        int B, C, D;
    };
} test123;


class Test {
    int ABCD;
public:
    void method(void){}

    Test(int val) :ABCD(val){}
    int getABCD(void) const { return ABCD; }
    int get2ABCD(void) const { return ABCD * 2; }
    int get3ABCD(void) const { return ABCD * 3; }
} test(0123);


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    // TEST_my_nullptr
    {
        int a = 321, *p = my_nullptr;
        assert(p == my_nullptr);
        assert(my_nullptr == p);

        p = &a; *p = 0123;
        assert(p != my_nullptr);
        assert(my_nullptr != p);

        p = my_nullptr;

        int(*mainptr)(int argc, char** argv) = my_nullptr;
        assert(mainptr == my_nullptr);
        assert(my_nullptr == mainptr);
    }


    // TEST_my_nullptr_const
    {
        const int a = 321, *p = my_nullptr;
        assert(p == my_nullptr);
        assert(my_nullptr == p);

        p = &a;
        assert(p != my_nullptr);
        assert(my_nullptr != p);

        const int** ptr = my_nullptr;

        assert(ptr == my_nullptr);
        assert(my_nullptr == ptr);

        ptr = &p;
        assert(ptr != my_nullptr);
        assert(my_nullptr != ptr);
        assert(*ptr != my_nullptr);
        assert(my_nullptr != *ptr);

    }


    // TEST_my_nullptr_member
    {
        int Test123::*pINT = my_nullptr;
        assert(pINT == my_nullptr);
        assert(my_nullptr == pINT);

        pINT = &Test123::ABCD;
        assert(pINT != my_nullptr);
        assert(my_nullptr != pINT);

        test123.*pINT = 0123;

        const int Test123::*pCINT = my_nullptr;
        assert(pCINT == my_nullptr);
        assert(my_nullptr == pCINT);

        pCINT = &Test123::ABCD;
        assert(pCINT != my_nullptr);
        assert(my_nullptr != pCINT);

        assert(test123.*pCINT == test123.*pINT);
    }

    // TEST_my_nullptr_Function
    {
        void (Test::*pm)(void) = &Test::method;

        pm = my_nullptr;

       > int (Test::*pABCD)(void) const = my_nullptr; // This Fxxk Line In VS2013

        pABCD = &Test::getABCD;

        int a1 = (test.*pABCD)();

        pABCD = &Test::get2ABCD;
        int a2 = (test.*pABCD)();

        pABCD = &Test::get3ABCD;
        int a3 = (test.*pABCD)();

        assert(a1 + a2 == a3);
    }

    std::cout << "All Tests for my_nullptr Passed!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[my Testsuit in GCC4.3.2](http://ideone.com/aX1OZ8)

Comment: Explicitly show at which line the error appears and show full error message.

Comment: You have an anonymous struct in your code.

Comment: Looks to be a MS bug on the `const` of the `pABCD` variable. Maybe file a bug report on http://connect.microsoft.com?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bug in VS2013. The bug seems to have been fixed in the VS14 CTP however, where your code compiles without errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is sadly not even wrong behaving.
As MS is with it's compilers not the most fast and it also is it not on interpretation of the standards, they are almost never close to it.

i.e. the MSVC2013 plain C compiler is a mixture of c89 and c99 clauses with many additional exceptions as not supporting stuff the standard says a c compiler HAS to support and also has many features which the standard says a c compiler is NOT ALLOWED to have.

So dont rely on the standard when compiling a c or c++ application with Microsoft Visual C compiler.

(thats probably why they call it Visual C, as they wouldn't even be allowed to call it plain C ;) )